# Play 1.2.4:Retrieving hidden variable value in Controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play 1.2.4 framework for my application.

I am setting the hidden variable in the .html file using this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test">
```

For retrieving the value of the hidden variable in controller, I used this:

```
String str = request.params.get("test");
```

But unfortunately the value of the String str is coming as `null` which means its not working.

Kindly let me know how to retrieve the hidden variables value in the controller.

**EDIT**

```
<center>            
    <table>         
        <tr style="height: 100px">
            <td><h1>
                    <b>Title</b>
                </h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>#{a @Application.userList()} Click Me#{/a}</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test">
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you please show the full html form ?

Comment: I have editted the post to provide the full HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your `<input>` tag enclosed by a `<form>` tag. Then, make a form request with your `<a>` tag. The code would look like this:

```
<center>
<table>
    <tr style="height: 100px">
        <td><h1>
                <b>Title</b>
            </h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="@{Application.userList()}" id="myform" method="get">
                <a onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">Click Me</a>
                <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```